# Group a DataTable into separate DataTables?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, .net-3.5

I have a DataTable which is like this -

```
EmpId,Country 
1,Germany
2,Germany
3,UK
4,UK
5,UK
6,France
7,USA
8,USA
```

I want to group by Country and extract all groups into separate datatables. So, we 
will have 4 groups/data tables. How do I do this ?

Stackoverflow won't let me paste fully working code. So here it is, thanks to 
@Myles B. Currie

Tested code -

```
public void main()
   {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet) Dts.Variables["obj_Rs"].Value;
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        List<DataTable> allCountryTables = new List<DataTable>();

        DataView view = new DataView(dt);
        DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Country");

        //Create new DataTable for each of the distinct countries 
        //identified and add to allCountryTables list

        foreach (DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
        {
            //Remove filters on view
            view.RowFilter = String.Empty;
            //get distinct country name
            String country = row["Country"].ToString();
            //filter view for that country
            view.RowFilter = "Country = " + "'" + country + "'";
            //export filtered view to new datatable
            DataTable countryTable = view.ToTable();
            //add new datatable to allCountryTables 
            allCountryTables.Add(countryTable);
        }//for each

        foreach(DataTable tbl in allCountryTables){

            String table = getDataTable(tbl);
            MessageBox.Show(table);

        }//for
}//main


    public static string getDataTable(DataTable dt){

        string table = "";

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
            {
                table = table + item.ToString() + "|";
            }//for

            table = table + Environment.NewLine;

        }//for

        return table;

    }//method
```

Comment: Group By USA, do you mean _group by Country_ instead?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes, I meant country. Fixing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not the shortest method of doing this but since you are saying you are having .Net version issues this is a long way to get the job done. (Below code is untested)

```
DataTable table; //Your Datatable
List<DataTable> allCountryTables = new List<DataTable>();

//Get distinct countries from table
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Country");

//Create new DataTable for each of the distinct countries identified and add to allCountryTables list    
foreach (DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
{
    //Remove filters on view
    view.RowFilter = String.Empty;
    //get distinct country name
    String country = row["Country"].ToString());
    //filter view for that country
    view.RowFilter = "Country = " + country;
    //export filtered view to new datatable
    DataTable countryTable = view.ToTable();
    //add new datatable to allCountryTables 
    allCountryTables.Add(countryTable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the only way out. There are some changes to your code. I'll add the edited code as an answer.

Comment: btw, why did you remove the filters on view ? view.RowFilter = String.Empty; What will happen if you don't do it ?

Comment: btw, is it possible to add more grouping conditions, besides country ?

Comment: View is a variable defined outside of the scope of the foreach loop. 
When you apply a filter to it you reduce the number of visible rows in the View. If you do not remove the filters applied before adding a new filter then your result would be only the rows that apply to all previously applied filters.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you mean by adding more grouping conditions. Do you mean you want Datatables where you have rows grouped by 2 columns e.g. country AND username or do you mean you want to group by only one column but have the code be dynamic that you can choose which column the data is grouped by?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
var countryGroups = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Country"));
```

Please remember about adding the following references:
System.Data.DataSetExtensions

Comment: Even after adding reference System.Core.dll and saving all, I get the error - 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Adding a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions should do the job

Comment: I tried tims code. After adding the Reference - System.Data.DataSetExtensions, I am getting an error - The type of the expression in the let clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'. Can you help me to fix that ?

Comment: Sorry, but are you using my code or the code of Tim Schmelter?

Comment: I want to try both. Does your code need more lines. I ask because tim is using more lines.

Comment: My code is shorter than Tim's but is not converting the result to DataTable. So in case it does not matter whether a result will be in DataTable or not, you should use my code. Otherwise you should try to use his code (the second part, because the first part is for VB.NET)

Comment: Your code also causes the error - 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added System.Linq and System.Linq.Expressions references and namespaces?

Comment: I added reference to assembly System.Data.Linq and also both namespaces. I could not find assembly for System.Linq.Expressions. I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to create a subset of DataTables for every country:

```
Dim groups = From row In tblEmp
             Let country = row.Field(Of String)("Country")
             Group row By country Into Group
             Select Group.CopyToDataTable()
Dim allCountryTables = groups.ToList()
```

Whoops, i was certain that there was a VB.NET tag....

```
var groups = from row in tblEmp.AsEnumerable()
             let country = row.Field<string>("Country")
             group row by country into Group
             select Group.CopyToDataTable();
List<DataTable> allCountryTables = groups.ToList();
```

Comment: Even after adding reference System.Core.dll and saving all, I get the error - 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: After adding the Reference -  System.Data.DataSetExtensions, I am getting an error - The type of the expression in the let clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.

Comment: Hmm, i have tested it with your sample table and. NET 4, I don't know what the problem is on 3.5. Sorry.

Comment: I created a question for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321761/the-type-of-the-expression-in-the-let-clause-is-incorrect-type-inference-failed